# HTML to PDF converter in php with support for svg?

Tags: php, html, pdf, svg

Do you know any php (4/5) library that would convert HTML string to PDF with support for svg?

Comment: This might help: http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php

Comment: Good tipp from Dainis, but note that mPDF is GPL licensed, which means, that you have to license your application as GPL as well.

Comment: I'm not sure that's always the case, if you use it as a library? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License#Libraries

Comment: (also, this is only if you 'release' your code, isn't it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) is not a PHP library, but in most cases, you'll be able to execute it with `exec()`. An example on how to do this is listed on the project page's wiki. Make sure that you CHMOD it to be executable (+x) via command line or your FTP client.

[Embedded SVG](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=835) has some caveats.